# Comparing two cells with two other cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

OK, So here is what I am working on.  I need column BU:BJ to show a match with BM:BO and show it in column BU.  The first one in BH (BH2:BJ2) matches with the last row (BM12:BO12) and returns a 1 (true) in BU2.  So far so good.  What I need is if column BH does not match anything in column BM then show either nothing or something other then a 0 or 1.

The formula I am using is =IF(IFERROR(MATCH(BH2,$BM$2:$BM$99)*MATCH(BJ2,$BO$2:$BO$99,0),0)>0,TRUE,FALSE)

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Need to look something like this in Column BU

[image]

Comment: Did you try formula auditing, looking at which part of your formula is not giving the expected result?

Comment: @Dominique Technically according to the formula I am using it is giving me the correct output.  I just need the flormula to output eith true, false of maybe a blank but can't figure out how to write the formula for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly based on your comments, you want a 1 when there are two matches, a 0 when there is one match, and a blank if there is no match?

In that case, try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(BH2,$BM$2:$BM$99,0))+ISNUMBER(MATCH(BJ2,$BO$2:$BO$99,0))=2, 1,
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(BH2,$BM$2:$BM$99,0))+ISNUMBER(MATCH(BJ2,$BO$2:$BO$99,0))=1, 0, ""))
```

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your output says 1 or 0, while I think you should output TRUE or FALSE:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(BH2,$BM$2:$BM$99)*MATCH(BJ2,$BO$2:$BO$99,0),0)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't ask the right way.  I have added another image to what I need.  Basically I need a "TRUE", "FALSE" and a third thing to show in the cell as either empty, or a "#" or whatever.  Something other then True or False.